# Why do Tasks within a Task sometimes execute and sometimes not?

Tags: c#, console-application, multitasking

in my (Console)application I have a task (levelATask), that starts other tasks (levelBTasks), which themselves start other tasks (levelCTasks).

Sometimes, my console application runs great and displays everything it should, but sometimes it only executes the levelATask, and none of the tasks within.

Here is my example:

I have `R_Machine.ExecuteSkill(S_Machine_Start);` R_Machine is of a class `Resource`. Resource has a `List` of class `Skill`.
 Skill has a method `Execute`, which wraps a `ExecuteMethod` in a Task. The ExectueMethod is a public property of Skill `public Action ExecuteMethod { get; set; }`

In Skill:

```
 private Task executingTask;
 /// <summary>
 /// Stuff that is exectued when the Skill is active
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="o"></param>
 public virtual void Execute(object o = null)
 {
     // if the executing task is not null and didnt already execute to completion
     if (executingTask == null || executingTask.IsCompleted)
     {
         // create the Task
         Task t = new Task(() =>
         {
             if (CanExecute())
             {
                 Logger.Debug($"Executing {Name} of {ExecutingResource.Name}");

                 SetActive();
                 ExecuteMethod();
                 SetFinished();

                 Logger.Debug($"Finished Executing {Name} of {ExecutingResource.Name}");
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FinishedStation))
                 {
                     Logger.Log(FinishedStation);
                 }
             }
         });

         // set it to the task created previously
         executingTask = t;
     }

     if (NeedsToExecute())
     {
         // if the task is not running or waiting for it
         if (executingTask.Status != TaskStatus.Running &&
             executingTask.Status != TaskStatus.WaitingToRun &&
             executingTask.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
         {   // run the task
             executingTask.Start();
         }
     }
 }
```

In Resource:

```
 public List<Skill> Skills { get; set; }

 public void ExecuteSkill(Skill s, object execParams = null)
 {
     if (!Skills.Contains(s))
     {
         Logger.Log($"Could not execute Skill {s.Name}, since it was not in list");

     }
     else
     {
         s.Execute(execParams);
     }
 }
```

In programm:

```
 S_Machine_Start.ExecuteMethod = new Action(() =>
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Machine Starts");
     R_St00.ExecuteSkill(S_St00_Start);
     R_St01.ExecuteSkill(S_St01_Start);
     R_St02.ExecuteSkill(S_St02_Start);
     R_St03.ExecuteSkill(S_St03_Start);
     R_St04.ExecuteSkill(S_St04_Start);
     R_St05.ExecuteSkill(S_St05_Start);
     R_St06.ExecuteSkill(S_St06_Start);
 });

 // similar for other stations
 S_St00_Start.ExecuteMethod = new Action(() =>
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Starting Station 0");                
     //create time with callback
     Timer t = new Timer(new TimerCallback((state) => {
         if (!pause)
         {
             R_St00_BowlFeeder.ExecuteSkill(S_St00_TransportB);
             R_St00_RotaryTable.ExecuteSkill(S_St00_Rotate);
             R_St00_Seperator.ExecuteSkill(S_St00_GoBack);
             R_St00_Seperator.ExecuteSkill(S_St00_Seperate);
         }
     }));
     // start timer with tick interval of 10ms
     t.Change(0, 10);
 });

 R_Machine.ExecuteSkill(S_Machine_Start);
```

Sometimes console shows :

- Machine Starts
- Starting Station 0
- Starting Station 1 ...
- Starting Station 0:  Rotate...

But sometimes console only shows:

- Machine Starts

I also write some line to debug window. When everything works fine it shows:

```
[15:13:14.796] Executing Machine Start 
[15:13:14.889] Finished Executing Machine Start 
[15:13:14.936] Executing St00 Start of St00
[15:13:14.969] Executing St06 Start of St06
[15:13:14.997] Finished Executing St00 Start of St00
[15:13:15.047] Executing St00 BowlFeeder Transport of St00 Conveyor
[15:13:14.997] Finished Executing St06 Start of St06
[15:13:15.051] Executing  of St05
[15:13:15.052] Finished Executing  of St05
[15:13:15.053] Executing  of St04
[15:13:15.054] Finished Executing  of St04
[15:13:15.055] Executing  of St03
[15:13:15.056] Finished Executing  of St03
[15:13:15.057] Executing St02 Start of St02
[15:13:15.058] Finished Executing St02 Start of St02
[15:13:15.059] Executing St01 Start of St01
[15:13:15.061] Finished Executing St01 Start of St01
```

Whenn it is not working it only shows:

```
[15:18:34.596] Executing Machine Start 
[15:18:34.688] Finished Executing Machine Start
```

I have VS 2017 Professional running on a Windows 7 VM. Sometimes it works, sometimes it does not.
A colleague has VS 2017 and 2019 Community Edition on Windows 10 (not Virtual Machine) and it never works.

Can somebody tell me why this migth happen and how I get it to always work correctly (exectuing all the tasks within other tasks)?

Thanks

**Edit:**
The complete code can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qwqdh0y66iuph0u/AACJo50EQLYtX6R9iljgAJyWa?dl=0

What I want to achive: This is basically a simulation for a plc of a machine. A cooperation partner created a model for the machine with the resources and skills. To validate if this model would work, I wrote this program simulation for the plc program sequence of a real machine using this model.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve].

Comment: What happens when `(executingTask == null || executingTask.IsCompleted)` is `false`? It looks like you're just throwing away the job. TBH, the code is completely infested with race-conditions and there are undocumented references to external state in your code that will make finding a direct solution near-on impossible. Are you sure you want to salvage it? Perhaps setting out a higher-level description of what you're trying to achieve might help us put you on a better path...

Comment: Two immediate thoughts: 1) if NeedsToExecute() is false, it looks like nothing happens. 2) You're just *starting* the task; I don't see anywhere where you're waiting for it to finish. That wouldn't be an issue if it was fully synchronous, but there's not enough information above to determine that.

Comment: @spender :  That is correct, however in the "In program" section of the code I try to execute the tast every 10 ms. Thats why there are all the executingTask.Status checks in the "In Skill" section. So a task of the same instance can not be run while the first one has not finished its execution ( a station in a machine can only process one part at a time, it can not start the processing of the same part again when it has not even finshed processing the part the first time)

Comment: @Thoms I think you need a queue somewhere.

Comment: The problem was indeed a race condition. See Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a race condition.
The starting of the stations in is only called once. For some of the stations the **CanExecute** method returned false because the machine has not set its running-flag.

So I implemented a timer as in **S_St00_Start.ExecuteMethod**.
Another solution would be a queue as @spender suggested.